# Image Transformation on iPhone, how to?

Tags: iphone, graphics, photoshop

Since I cannot pre-render all the images in PNGs and real-time  image transformation functions are required, namely:

- skew
- perspective

(like the transform action found in Photoshop)

Which API (CoreAnimation? OpenGL ES?) should I look into? Even better, is there any sample code around? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For skew/shear you can use:

```
CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMakeShear( CGFloat inX , CGFloat inY ) {
    return CGAffineTransformMake( 1 , inY , inX , 1 , 0 , 0 );
}
```

For perspective, a 2D affine transform is insufficient.  You can apply a 3D affine transform to a layer and get the results that perspective is trying to emulate.

```
myView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( ... );
```